# how to share the admin configurations in magento 2.2.x

Tags: magento2, importexport

I am working with git, so i have added a module inside the project with code controllers,blocks,templates... and i have done also some change on this module's configuration on admin backend, so when i push my branch to git the others do 'git pull' from my branch they have the code which i have added but not the changes of the configuration in admin backend for this module ,

> I have seen the doc here ==> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/example/shared-configuration.html

they provide the solution but, they provide a command which is "***php bin/magento app:config:dump***" that means the all changes will be moves to config.php , but i want just to export the change for the module which i was added for example 'myModule'

Can anyone please help me to do that ? I will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

https://github.com/semaio/Magento2-ConfigImportExport

Lets you also apply configs base on environments.

Comment: Thank you for responding , but i don't wanna to install any stranger modules , for security reason  , i want just to do it by the command above

Comment: well you can't. if you want to set default values for your config you should use the config.xml

Comment: how can i do it please